# Overriding rem in a component

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have written a component for a website that renders some HTML, and styles this HTML with CSS. So far, so good. Now we have the following constraints:

- The website sets a `font-size` for `body` of `14px` (this is not under my control).
- The CSS of the component makes use of `rem` for `font-size` (this is not under my control either).

Now the problem is that the component renders too small, because it assumes to have a `font-size` of `body` of `16px`. Yes, I know, the question of course is why `rem` is then used, but as said, this is outside of my control

Now my question: Assumed I want the component to use a base `font-size` of `16px`, and assumed that I need to stick with `rem`, and assumed that I need to stick with `14px` for `body` - what is the easiest way to fix this mess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set font size on html because rem is relative to it.

```
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

or

```
:root {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)

Comment: But this then changes the entire style of the website, which is not desired, doesn't it?

Comment: It doesn't, because html font size is overriden by body font size. In other words rems are relative to html, but other units are relatives to body or body descendants font sizes.

Comment: It does. The desired result is for the web component to use rem within it, relative to its root, without modifying the styles of the page the component is within.